# rails has_scope and sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx, has-scope

In my application I use `has_scope` gem and `thinking sphinx`, and in model I have written something like:

```
scope :by_description, -> description { where("description like ?", "%#{description}%") if description.present?}
```

and then, In controller:

```
has_scope :by_description

def somemimimi
  @cars = apply_scopes(Car).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

but when I tried to write something like:

```
scope :by_description, -> description { search description}
```

I got the following error

```
 you cannot search with Sphinx through ActiveRecord scopes
```

but I just search with sphinx too (when this param is presented), How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `has_scope` gem will work with Thinking Sphinx scopes, but you could try the following in your model (which replaces your existing ActiveRecord scope):

```
include ThinkingSphinx::Scopes

sphinx_scope(:by_description) { |description| description }
```

But please keep in mind that what this scope returns is a Thinking Sphinx search object, not an ActiveRecord relation, so you can't use it combined with ActiveRecord methods like `where` or `order` (and you can't call any ActiveRecord scopes on it either). So, what you chain on after the `apply_scopes` call in your controller will need to be adapted. Perhaps as follows:

```
@cars = apply_scopes(Car).search(order: 'created_at DESC', page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

However, this is all built upon the presumption that the `has_scope` gem is simple enough in its approach that it'll just call class-level methods on the given model, whether they're ActiveRecord scopes or not.

From a perspective of avoiding issues from changes in the `has_scope` gem, I'd recommend not using it with Thinking Sphinx queries.

Comment: but how then use scopes and morf.search?

Comment: `@cars = apply_scopes(Car).search(order: 'description DESC', page: params[:page], per_page: 20)` works, but when i change to `created_at` - no, but how to search with ordering without adding field to index?

Comment: Whatever you sort by in a search call must be an attribute (or a sortable field). Sphinx can only sort using the data available in its indices.

Comment: If there are other issues, perhaps it's worth starting another question? It is hard to discuss the details (error messages, stack traces, index definitions, gem versions, etc) in comment threads.